# taking Full Screen Shot Of list activity in Android While Using OS Marshmallow..?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

How can I get a full screen shot of an activity which contains list view. I have done it with all other os, lower than marshmallow. In mobile which is containing marshmallow os it takes only the screen shot of the viewing content on view or in mobile screen viewing content.In Short marshmallow does not allow me to take a full screen shot of the activity. How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.
Here is Some Code:

```
private void pdf() {
   // fn_permission();
    printhelper=new PrintHelper(ConversionEnergyListActivity.this);
    printhelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".JPEG";
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_conversion_list, null); //RelativeLayout is root view of my UI(xml) file.
    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap= getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.relativelayout));
    imageFile = new File(mPath);
    try{
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        // Toast.makeText(ConversionEnergyListActivity.this,"Image path : "+imageFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//create bitmap from view and returns it
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
   // Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
  /*  //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }   else{
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }*/
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: show some code how do you obtaining "screenshot" currently

Comment: private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
    
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

Comment: looks good, what are you passing to method as a `view`? show more code, edit question, don't put in comment, its unreadable...

Comment: ok fine.I Have edited my questions.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line inside `pdf` method

```
bitmap= getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.relativelayout));
```

to this

```
bitmap = getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().getDecorView());
```

and also inside `getBitmapFromView` method:

```
view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
```

to

```
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
```